# few times get error code for didFailWithError as 0 in locationmanager delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, didfailwitherror

```
- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError: (NSError *)error
```

Few times on running on iPad (3rd gen - wifi only) perfect condition (good internet) I get 'error code' as 0 in the above method.

Error code from here - 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corelocation/reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kCLErrorDenied

Now the question is why this delegate method is being called even when there is decent network connectivity. It happens only few times and when this method is called it continues for 3-4 times and then due to timeout error I show location not found to user.

I tested in other apps and looks like other apps have no issue in the same network connectivity and fetches current location smoothly.

Any help/guidance is appreciated on debugging this issue.